# Can the Cavalier use a Holy Avenger?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, adnd-1e

Can the Cavalier class from the AD&D *Unearthed Arcana* use a Holy Avenger?

Comment: Hi @Zack and welcome to the site.  Could you let us know what version of D&D you're playing, and which version of the Cavalier (ie: which supplement)?

Answer (score 6):

In AD&D, any fighter of correct alignment can use one, but only a Paladin gains full benefit. Players of wrong alignment take side effects for use of it.

Answer (score 4):

A Cavalier can wield a Holy Avenger as a +2 sword.

The Holy Avenger can be used by **any** character as a +2 sword with no special properties.  Per the DMG, there are no side effects for any wielders unless the sword is intelligent in which case any non-lawful good character would take the normal damage based on the sword's ego every time they handled the sword.

Only a Paladin can use the **Holy Avenger** to its true potential

- The full +5
- Magic resistance of 50% in a 5' radius
- Dispel Magic
- +10 bonus damage against chaotic evil opponents

A Paladin is a subclass of Cavalier per the Unearthed Arcana.  There is no mention of the Cavalier counting as a Paladin for usage of a Holy Avenger.  Instead the Paladin gains several of the Cavalier's advantages:

- Weapons of Choice
- Parrying
- Horsemanship
- Saving throw bonuses
- Immunity to fear
- ability score increases

Answer (score 1):

In [D&D 3.x](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/magicWeapons.htm#holyAvenger) and [Pathfinder](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-weapons#TOC-Holy-Avenger) anyone can wield a Holy Avenger but only Paladins gain the complete benefits and use of the sword.  For Pathfinder there is nothing to indicate that the [Cavalier](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/cavalier) class (from the Advanced Player's Guide) would gain the paladin benefits when wielding a Holy Avenger.